# Triple Cryptics

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues, letters

> Here's an attempt at a new twist on cryptic clues.  The following clues do **NOT** have a definition section.  However, the wordplay is keyed in *three* different ways. Can you work out the words?

1. User error sure destroyed note about American (4)
2. Spouse embraces, and Amanda tempts some guy with fruit (7)
3. Spins yarn about time drain outside street marker (5)
4. Lost mail after last month and claimed weird medical condition (7)
5. Weak ruler with knight in wild object without color (8)
6. Hurt pride about a return to help each, compensated back (6)
7. Dad's about right, an hour in a wind-breaker means almost there after a long way (7)
8. I drove out with no right to provide only fragments for a word book before 4 left. (5)
9. Near miss takes a thousand or nothing from fruit for anger management (5)
10. Toffee and tea cut away from bottom of shield? (6)
11. Teach bad route around idle chatter, rodent boy (7)
12. Short King spills bile and I bleed out as the Spanish remain back (7)
13. Dangerous regions, in parts of, malign or eschew singing our sets regularly (7)
14. I sat back with nothing, stuck in a riot, as even I won't pass (5)
15. Wrote about the extreme terror having to be in debt, and threw other parts back (5)
16. The test won't end in a month, time in ruin, I bend towards start in fuzzy arm chair (9)
17. Time and distance aboard shifty river is found in exotic tangles; your first small endeavor takes spirit (9)
18. Mess core up to procure fashion, with no Romeo to catch again, you hear? (6)
19. First one did a part, and doesn't resort to this ending well-defined (6)
20. The same mixed gin means don't start grieving, take five and veg out around the back-nine (8)

**EDIT:  Enumerations added**

Gareth McCaughan has gotten them all with help from Rubio!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
User error sure destroyed note about American
```

> RUSE [USER*; SURE*; RE around US]

```
Spouse embraces, and Amanda tempts some guy with fruit
```

> MANDATE [M(AND)ATE; aMANDATEmpts; MAN+DATE]

```
Spins yarn about time drain outside street marker
```

> STINK [KNITS<; T, SINK outside; ST+INK]

```
Lost mail after last month and claimed weird medical condition
```

> DECLAIM [DEC+MAIL*; CLAIMED*; MEDICAL*]

```
Weak ruler with knight in wild object without color
```

> THINKING [THIN KING; (KNIGHT IN)*; TH(INK)ING]

```
Hurt pride about a return to help each, compensated back
```

> DIAPER [PRIDE* around A; AID<+PER; REPAID<; thanks to Rubio for pointing out that what I had here before was wrong; I haven't checked whether this matches his but I bet it does]

```
Dad's about right, an hour in a wind-breaker means almost there after a long way
```

> FARTHER [FA(R)THER; FART(H)ER; FAR+THER(e)]

```
I drove out with no right to provide only fragments for a word book before 4 left.
```

> VIDEO [ID(r)OVE*; proVIDEOnly; (OED+IV)<]

```
Near miss takes a thousand or nothing from fruit for anger management
```

> RANGE [G in NEAR*; (o)RANGE; ANGER*]

```
Toffee and tea cut away from bottom of shield?
```

> OFFEND [(TOFFEEAND-TEA)*; OFF END; OF+FEND]

```
Teach bad route around idle chatter, rodent boy
```

> RATCHET [RT around TEACH*; CHATTER*; RAT+CHET]

```
Short King spills bile and I bleed out as the Spanish remain back
```

> EDIBLE [ED+BILE*; IBLEED*; (EL BIDE)<]

```
Dangerous regions, in parts of, malign or eschew singing our sets regularly
```

> IGNORES [REGIONS*; malIGNORESchew; sInGiNgOuRsEtS]

```
I sat back with nothing, stuck in a riot, as even I won't pass
```

> IOTAS [I + SAT< with O in; rIOTAS; IwOnTpAsS]

```
Wrote about the extreme terror having to be in debt, and threw other parts back
```

> TOWER [WROTE*; TR containing OWE; thREWOTher]

```
The test won't end in a month, time in ruin, I bend towards start in fuzzy arm chair
```

> MATRIARCH [TRIA(l) in MARCH; (T in MAR) + I ARCH; T(owards) in ARMCHAIR*]

```
Time and distance aboard shifty river is found in exotic tangles; your first small endeavor takes spirit
```

> STRANGELY [T+RANGE in SLY; R in TANGLES*; S+TRY containing ANGEL]

```
Mess core up to procure fashion, with no Romeo to catch again, you hear?
```

> RECOUP [COREUP*; (PROCURE-R)*; sounds like RE-COOP]

```
First one did a part, and doesn't resort to this ending well-defined
```

> STONED [firSTONEDid; DOESNT*; (thi)S+TONED]

```
The same mixed gin means don't start grieving, take five and veg out around the back-nine
```

> EVENING [EVEN+GIN*; (k)EENING containing V; VEG* around NINE<]

(Enumerations would have been nice...) [EDITED to add:] Aha, OP has provided them now. I regret that I am too lazy to edit them into the above.

Comment: Your 6 is wrong, feel free to crib mine. I concede, you're much faster than I am :)

Comment: 'Tis wrong indeed. I'm afraid my vanity made me do it myself :-). (Not that I have any way of proving I _haven't_ been cribbing your answers, of course.)

Comment: Nice work so far!  I swear the enumerations were part of the text that I copied in, but it seems to have lost them.  I'll have them  edited back in by tomorrow,

Comment: Your edit for number 8 is correct!  #3 is all that's left.  You have the first 2 letters correct there.

Comment: Great work, that's all twenty, I wish more people were giving you upvotes for this effort.

Comment: It's OK. I'm not exactly hurting for Meaningless Internet Points here.

Answer (score 3):

#### partial

1 — User error sure destroyed note about American

> **RUSE** = (USER)* / (SURE)* / R(US)E

2 — Spouse embraces, and Amanda tempts some guy with fruit

> **MANDATE** = M(AND)ATE / aMANDATEmpts / MAN + DATE

3 — Spins yarn about time drain outside street marker

4 — Lost mail after last month and claimed weird medical condition

5 — Weak ruler with knight in wild object without color

6 — Hurt pride about a return to help each, compensated back

> **DIAPER** = (PRIDE)* around A / AID< + PER / (REPAID)<

7 — Dad's about right, an hour in a wind-breaker means almost there after a long way

> **FARTHER** = FA(R)THER / FART(H)ER / FAR + THER[-e]

8 — I drove out with no right to provide only fragments for a word book before 4 left.

9 — Near miss takes a thousand or nothing from fruit for anger management

> **RANGE** = RAN(G)E / [-o]RANGE / (ANGER)*

10 — Toffee and tea cut away from bottom of shield?

11 — Teach bad route around idle chatter, rodent boy

> **RATCHET** = (TEACH)* around RT ?? / (CHATTER)* / RAT + CHET

12 — Short King spills bile and I bleed out as the Spanish remain back

13 — Dangerous regions, in parts of, malign or eschew singing our sets regularly

14 — I sat back with nothing, stuck in a riot, as even I won't pass

15 — Wrote about the extreme terror having to be in debt, and threw other parts back

16 — The test won't end in a month, time in ruin, I bend towards start in fuzzy arm chair

17 — Time and distance aboard shifty river is found in exotic tangles; your first small endeavor takes spirit

18 — Mess core up to procure fashion, with no Romeo to catch again, you hear?

> **RECOUP** = (CORE UP)* / (PROCU[-r]E)* / RECOOP, *(aud.)*

19 — First one did a part, and doesn't resort to this ending well-defined

> **STONED** = firST ONE Did (a part) / (DOESNT)* / _S + TONED

20 — The same mixed gin means don't start grieving, take five and veg out around the back-nine

Comment: 8 is very stupid

Comment: c-could 3 b-b-be?

Comment: All correct!  As I told Gareth the enumerations should have been included and I'll  put them in tomorrow morning.